# NativeBase Button doesn't show text

Tags: javascript, react-native, native-base

I have the issue that my buttons from NativeBase do not show their text. I pretty much used the sample code from the documentation of their website, but when I render it it shows three buttons that I can touch, but without any title. Any ideas? Please see code:

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import MenuButton from './MenuButton';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Welcome to the App</Text>
        <MenuButton/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    top: 40,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  textStyle:{
   fontSize: 30
  }
});
```

MenuButton.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Container, Content, Button, Badge } from 'native-base';
export default class MenuButtons extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <Content>
                    <Button style={styles.button} textStyle={styles.buttonText}> HeLLO!! </Button>
                    <Button style={styles.button} bordered large> Info </Button>
                    <Button style={styles.button} bordered capitalize={true}> Primary </Button>
                </Content>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    button: {
        backgroundColor: 'orange',
        paddingBottom: 30,
        paddingTop: 30,
        width: 350,
        height:40,
    },
    buttonText:{
        fontSize:40,
        color:'black'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just deleted the "paddingTop" and "paddingBottom" props and the text started to appear.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap the text with `<Text>` tags inside Button opening and closing tags, Try this link. https://snack.expo.io/r1eDZ0wUX (Edited - Removed padding styles from the button too)

```
<Button style={styles.button}><Text style={styles.buttonText}>HeLLO!!</Text></Button>
<Button style={styles.button} bordered large><Text>Info</Text></Button>
<Button style={styles.button} bordered><Text>Primary</Text></Button>
```

Comment: I was tried this in snack of expo, (https://snack.expo.io/r1eDZ0wUX). I was removed paddingTop and paddingBottom from styles. Didn't add it to the solution and sorry about that. Here I updated my solution with the link.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the code snippet, it seems that you are not following the documentation.

`Text` is imported from `native-base`, and not from `react-native`