# Text in Button doesn't show text in ios (native base)

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, native-base

hi in my project I use `nativeBase`. I use `<Button><Text>blablabla</Text></Button>`
when running in android ok but when run-ios text not showing.
this is my component :

```js
<View style={{ marginLeft: 7, flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
  <View style={styles.btncontent}>
    <Right style={{ flex: 0.2 }}>
      <Image source={mapBtnLogo} style={styles.btnImage} />
    </Right>
    <Left style={{ flex: 0.8 }}>
      <Button full transparent style={styles.btn} onPress={() => props.myProps.gotoMap([section.YPOINT, section.XPOINT])}>
        <Text style={styles.btnText}>
          نمایش روی نقشه
                </Text>
      </Button>
    </Left>
  </View>
</View>
```

and this is `styles` :

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  ...Platform.select({
    ios: {
      btnImage: {
        margin: 5,
        marginRight: 20,
        width: moderateScale(20),
        height: moderateScale(20),
      },
      btn: {
        //alignItems: 'flex-start',
        width: '100%',
        height: '10%',

      },
      btnText: {
        fontFamily: 'IRANSansMobile',
        fontSize: 15,
        color: '#000',
      },
    }, android: {
      btn: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '10%',
      },
      btnText: {
        fontFamily: 'IRANSansMobile',
        fontSize: 15,
        color: '#000000'
      },
      btncontent: {
        backgroundColor: '#59c5b8',
        flexDirection: 'row-reverse',
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderWidth: 0.3,
        borderRadius: 5,
        marginLeft: 10,
        width: '95%',
      },
    }
```

remove `node module` and install again not working.
and clear Xcode and run again but not working.
I read this post [NativeBase Button doesn't show text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51888060/nativebase-button-doesnt-show-text) but I don't use `padding` and still not showing text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake in styling :

change height style `btn` in the stylesheet from `10%` to `100%` !!

thank

Answer (score 0):

You can try `TouchableOpacity`.

```js
<Left style={{ flex: 0.8 }}>
  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn} onPress={() => props.myProps.gotoMap([section.YPOINT, section.XPOINT])}>
    <Text style={styles.btnText}>
      نمایش روی نقشه
                </Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
</Left>
```